Laravel model with relationship loads all records not only relationships
I have a model called MeterReading, and another called Client, where a client can have multiple meter readings.
here are the relationships as defined:
in Client
public function readings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MeterReading::class)->orderByDesc('created_at');
}

and in MeterReading
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class)->withTrashed();
}

and both have the relationships defined in:
 protected $with 

now, when I load meter readings using queries, like this one:
    $readings= MeterReading::where('month', $this->month)
        ->where('year', $this->year)
        ->orderByDesc('meter_readings.created_at')->paginate($this->perPage);

It loads all the 4000 records of clients, not only those related to the selected readings, and upon investigation, I found that it calls the clients as follows:
select * from `clients` where `clients`.`id` in (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

the migrations are defined correctly, and both clients.id and client_id are matching types.
Note that client ids are unique of course, and they are a formatted string, and cannot be null nor 0.
why does this happen? any ideas to fix this?

if clients.id cannot be null nor 0 why does'clients'.'id' in (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) load 4000 clients than?

instead of prodected $witdh why you dont user eager loading directly like
'    ->with(['client' => function ($query) {
$query->withTrashed();
}])' ?

@Soteris92 , I tried and it gives the same result.

@krisgjika I have no idea, but i tried it in a simple query and it fact does the same, id=0 loads all the records.
and why does it give ids as 0s in the first place?

@Tamer sounds like somewhere a null is being cast as 0, try yo declare the relationship columns on the methods in case laravel is guessing the wrong name

if that does not work you need to provide the db schema of these related tables
